# Copying a licence for Coda for another user on the same computer Mac

Tags: macos, coda

An account on my Mac has a full version of coda installed. How can I copy this licence so another user on the same computer can use it. I do not have the serial to hand, could I just copy a certian file?

Comment: You should ask Coda support.

Answer (score 1):

Your serial *is* to hand, you can request it [**right under the header**](http://www.panic.com/coda/support.html)  at their FAQ.

No need to transfer your license, the location of your license isn't known anyway...

If for any reason you can't obtain your serial, we can't help you further as that wouldn't be legal.